# CertificateChain is null when importing pkcs12 (.p12) client-certificate file in Java Keystore

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, keystore, pkcs#12

I exported a client-ssl-certificate KeyPair with certificate chain as PKCS12 file keystore explorer. I am able to load this PKCS12 file with KSE again, and the keypair as well as the certificate chain is there. When i load it into a java KeyStore, i am able to access the Key, but the certificate chain is null.

This is my code:

```
        final KeyStore instance = KeyStore.getInstance( "pkcs12" );
        instance.load( new ByteArrayInputStream( bytes ), password );

        instance.getKey(alias, password) => returns Key
        instance.getCertificateChain(alias) => returns null

        final KeyStore.ProtectionParameter param = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection( password );
        final KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) instance.getEntry( alias, param );

        => fails:

java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input
    at java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry.<init>(KeyStore.java:524) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1311) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1521) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
```

With debugging i can see, that the constructor of PrivateKeyEntry is called with the chain argument nulled:

[image: debugging PrivateKeyEntry constructor call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZTqk.png)

I have absolutely no explaination for this, and found no information on the internet.

I can exclude the used alias and the used password as the reason.

I woul apprecciate any hints regarding this topic.

Thanks in advance,

Alexander

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed and are you able to run the `openssl` command-line tool?  If so, post the output from `openssl pkcs12 -in /path/to/your/file.p12 -nodes`.  Make sure you *don't* post the part between the `BEGIN` and `END` for the private key.  That will verify that your PKCS12 file is properly constructed.

Comment: Hi Andrew Henle, when im doing this, it outputs the chain as PEM. Seems fine to me.

Comment: Is there a `PRIVATE KEY` portion in the output?

Comment: Can you reproduce with a dummy or test-only key -- one that you can safely expose -- and provide that actual P12 file, either in a binary-preserving form like base64 or hex, or on something like pastebin?

Comment: @Andrew Henle, yes, the private key is also outputted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here:

https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/security/KeyStore.java#L523

The exception is thrown in one of the three scenarios:

1. You have a key but no private key.
2. You have no chain (thats what you said).
3. You have no attributes.

To make sure the chain is the problem you could activate the debugging using

```
 -Djava.security.debug=all
```

Comment: i tried to use the option, but i there was no additional output

Comment: @AlexanderM. What does `sun.security.util.Debug.isOn("all")` say?

Comment: it returned false. Seems that passing VM Options in intelliJ RunConfig doesnt work with springBoot (bootRun). I set the property with Gradle and now it works! Thanks for the tip

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was able to solve it! the certificate was exported without a password. And for the password null was passed to the KeyStore::load method. Passing an empty char array instead of null did the trick!

Comment: @AlexanderM. This did it for me too! Thanks

Comment: Where to pass this flag?

Comment: @kiner_shah At the end of the keytool-command AFAIK. As you might notice, the Keytool is compleatly written in Java, so if you are a java-developer you will be able to debug keytool.